# http calls in polymer component as compared to angularjs services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have one service which is being used by different webcomponents in my application. So i am thinking to create a webcomponent which will have my service and can be imported in my webcomponents wherever needed just as is done in angularjs.

**In Angular**

```
app.service('myService', function () {
    this.hello = function () {
        return "Hello World";
    };
    this.getData= function() {
      return $http({
        method: 'JSON', 
        url: 'SomeURL'
      });
}
```

**In Polymer**

```
<dom-module id="my-service">
    <script>

    var myService= new Object();

    myService.hello = function () {
        return "Hello World";
    };

    myService.getData= function() {
      //How to convert this part in polymer context or we need to use <iron-ajax> , if yes then how?
      });
    }
</script>
```

Can anybody tell me what is the best way to achieve the same in Polymer.

Any help will be highly appreciated !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way which I found to implement service ([Polymer 2 docs](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements)) is :

Axios : [Axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios)

```
<script>

class MyService extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() { return 'my-service; }
  static get properties() { url: 'my/service-url' }

  getEndpoint(id) {
    axios.get(this.url, {
      params: {
       ID: id
      }
    })
   .then(function (response) {
     console.log(response);
    })
  }

  postEndpoint(params) {
    //Use axios to post data from backend
  }
}

customElements.define(MyService.is, MyService);
</script>
```

Hope it also helps you!!